# Merging incidents with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have incidents. Incident record has fields (meaningful):

`from_ts` - when incidents started, timestamp,

`to_ts` - when incident finished, timestamp.

Incident records are being constantly produced by Flink and sent to Kafka topic.

The task is to transfer data from Kafka topic to Postgres table. In common it is easy to do with JbdcSinkConnector if there is no need to process data before insert.

But I need to do some merging before. Let's imagine that we have three incidents in Kafka topic:

```
from_ts | to_ts  
----------------
1       | 2    
3       | 7
10      | 15
```

Two incidents are supposed to be a single incident if difference between `to_ts` of the first one and `from_ts` of the second one is less than two seconds. So in Postgres table must be two records:

```
from_ts | to_ts  
----------------
1       | 7    
10      | 15
```

As we can see incidents 1 and 2 were merged.

Could you say, please, does Kafka able to do merging of that sort? If yes please give me direction to dive into.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try looking up Kafka Streams (aka KStreams). And as you're done  finalizing the data processing in Kafka, you can easily load the changes into postgres using kafka-connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kafka itself has no "processing" capability - you can produce records, and consume records, but there's nowhere to maintain this state.

it sounds like you need a "query-modify-write" operation when you process a record. if your state is in postgres you'd need to write this code on top of a consumer poll loop. if you move your state from postgres and use something like kafka streams it may be simpler to write this code (but it may be more difficult to get access to the results, depends on whats reading out of postgres in your case)

Comment: I was afraid of answers like that. Well, life is hard. Thanks for answering

Comment: "nowhere to maintain state" - RocksDB? A changelog and statestore topic?

Comment: i meant no convenient facility in core kafka. you'd need to "upgrade" to kafka-streams to get anything like that